# Getting Error On Xml resultSet in java

Tags: java

when i try run to execute java code it displays error. which i used to get xml type resultset from oracle using flowing method in java

```
 poxml = XMLType(rs.getOPAQUE(1));
```

it shows cannot find symbol  --- symbol  : method getOPAQUE(int)

any one  can suggest any other method for retrieving the xml resulset values from oracle

Comment: This question needs to be phrased more clearly and with more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You mention an execution error but describe a compiler error: `cannot find symbol`. Be sure you `import oracle.xdb.XMLType;` and include the actual text of the errors you get. Also, compare what your doing to the [XMLType examples](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10492/xdb11jav.htm#ADXDB4934) in the [*XML DB Developer's Guide*](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10492/toc.htm).